# Command definition in a different class

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, command

I'm new to WPF so I'm not sure if what I'm doing makes any sense.. anyway: I'm trying to implement a command for a button that uses ApplicationCommands.Open.
In my XAML I have:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"                
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"                
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"                
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ViewModel"                
        Title="MainWindow" Height="650" Width="1170">                
    <Window.DataContext>                
        <local:ResourceListViewModel/>                
    </Window.DataContext>
```

I want to have a command definition in a local:ResourceListViewModel class, so so far I got there:

```
void OpenCmdExecuted(object target, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("The command has been invoked");
        }

        void OpenCmdCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }
```

So what I think I must do is to bind these methods to a command, so I'm trying to do it this way:

```
 <Window.CommandBindings >
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"
                  Executed="OpenCmdExecuted"
                  CanExecute="OpenCmdCanExecute"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
```

but the program is not compiling as it seems to be looking for these functions in MainWindow. How can I let the program know that my functions' definitions are in a different class?

Comment: Your DataContext should handle this. What compile errors are you getting?

Comment: @TMan I'm getting: Error 1 'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'OpenCmdExecuted' and no extension method 'OpenCmdExecuted' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I think the way you are setting this up only works for code behind. Look into ICommand or maybe even Expression Interactivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the way Commands work in MVVM. There is a difference between `RoutedCommand`s (such as `ApplicationCommands.Open`, and `DelegateCommand`s (a.k.a `RelayCommand`s).

The first are View-related and bubble up the visual tree, etc, and have to be handled by the View in code-behind.

The second are ViewModel-related and are defined in the ViewModel (meaning the Command instance is a property member of the ViewModel itself)

```
public class ResourceListViewModel
{
    public RelayCommand OpenCommand {get;set;}

    public ResourceListViewModel()
    {
        OpenCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteOpenCommand, CanExecuteOpenCommand);
    }

    //etc etc
}
```